# Is it possible to move files from one folder of S3 bucket to the other folder of S3 bucket by using Pentaho?

Tags: amazon-s3, pentaho

I am trying to search a component which can help me to move file from one S3 bucket folder to another in Pentaho Data Integration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Python Executor](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/Python_Executor) step in Pentaho to write a python script to call AWS boto library and to copy the data from one folder to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pentaho to move files from one folder of the S3 bucket to the other folder of the S3 bucket.

1. You need to set up VFS Connections. You can follow the steps to set up AWS S3 from [documentation](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Products/Connecting_to_Virtual_File_Systems)
2. Once you set up VFS, you can use the "Hadoop copy files" step in the job to copy files or if you want to move files, you can check "Remove source files" in the Settings tab

[image: s3-1]

[image: s3-2]